# passportjs configuration `Done` callback

Tags: node.js, express, callback, passport.js

I have been studying the [Passport configure documention](http://www.passportjs.org/docs/configure/) -

```
var passport = require('passport')
  , LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
  function(username, password, done) {
    User.findOne({ username: username }, function (err, user) {
      if (err) { return done(err); }
      if (!user) {
        return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect username.' });
      }
      if (!user.validPassword(password)) {
        return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect password.' });
      }
      return done(null, user);
    });
  }
));
```

According to the docs, if the credentials are valid, the verify callback `function(username, password, done){...}` invokes `done` to supply Passport with the user that authenticated. Since `done` is also callback function, I would expect its function body to be passed in as a parameter of the verify callback. In the [Express 4.x Passport example](https://github.com/passport/express-4.x-local-example/blob/master/server.js), the code is similar except the `done` is called `cb`. What is the benefit of being able to change its name? In both cases, I can't find the body of the callback so I assume it is part of Passport - is this correct? The documentation give examples how to call `Done` but I can't find its API call signature. In the first example, result calling `Done` is returned (for example `return done(null, user);`) but how do we know what `Done` actually returns?

Answer (score 1):

It makes no difference what you call the callback. It's like a `(req, res, next)` in Express.js, you can call it: `(request, response, nextFunc)`, but it doesn't change a function work

Comment: Do you mean `done` and `cb` are two names for the same [formal parameter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parameter_(computer_programming))? If so, how is the corresponding actual parameter supplied?

Comment: @user2309803 you can call them whatever you want, it's just a function that takes 3 parameters, and it doesn't care what they are called

Comment: The developer does not seem to pass in the implementation of `done` so what is the use of having this 3rd parameter of the verify callback?

Comment: @user2309803 done simply indicates that the process has ended or was called with an error. It is a kind of object to maintain the middlewares on which Express is built. All passport.js is built on Express and its approach to using middlewares. Inside passoprt.js done is analogue to next from (req, req, next). Don't look for any hidden meaning here, it's just middleware (http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html)

Answer (score 1):

> What is the benefit of being able to change its name?

You can name function parameters whatever you like. That's just how functions work.

Express couldn't stop you from writing your function as `function(alice, bob, charline)` however nonsensical that might be.

> In both cases, I can't find the body of the callback so I assume it is part of Passport - is this correct? The documentation give examples how to call Done but I can't find its API call signature.

It's in the [Strategy section](http://www.passportjs.org/docs/configure/) under "Verify Callback".

> In the first example, result calling Done is returned (for example return done(null, user);) but how do we know what Done actually returns?

You could log it and see, but the documentation doesn't mention what it returns, only the arguments it accepts. The use of a `return` statement is most likely to exit the function so no further processing is performed.

Comment: Thanks for you answers. Is the `done` function implemented within Passport? If so, why is necessary to pass the `done` callback function in the 3rd parameter of the verify callback?

Comment: "Thanks for you answers. Is the done function implemented within Passport?" — Yes

Comment: "If so, why is necessary to pass the done callback function in the 3rd parameter of the verify callback?" — You don't. It is passed **to** the third parameter of that function, and it has to be otherwise you wouldn't be able to call it.

Comment: If `done` is provided by Passport, why can't it be called directly like any other library function?

Comment: For the same reason that you can't call `res.send()` by accessing `res` *directly*. It's generated for the context.

Comment: That's good point - my question why is  `done` called via callback parameter of the verify callback is equivalent to asking why is `res.send` called via a callback parameter of `app.get` and that is my real question. Thanks for your time.